# How to install the "SpaCy" library without get this Error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, nlp, spacy

I tried for a few days to install spaCy and it's giving me different errors.
now it gives me this error (attached link to the error):

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_n1WB-HlVPTHHlsBJ0zpdQYYHlInM-W/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using 32-bit Python - which is not supported anymore by spaCy, see [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/README.md#install-spacy).